# PHP iOS push-notifications

Tags: php, ios

I would create a web application that sends push-notifications to my iPhone when a person filled in a form. How can I send that notification through PHP to my iPhone?

Comment: This is far too general to post here. Please add some code or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through [Apple Push Notification Services in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) which guides you through everything you will need from creating the certificates/keys to giving you some PHP to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parse API available on http://www.parse.com to send push notifications easily :)